# How is the angle same in friction force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

How is the angle $\theta$ of the plane and between the $mg$ (attraction due to gravity) and component of $mg$ is same?

[image]

In the figure $\theta$ between the $mg$ and its component $$mg\cos\theta$$ is same as the angle between the horizontal surface and the inclined plane. How?

Comment: "Angle between two lines is same as angle between their normals"

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that.

Comment: This should be something proved in a geometry class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle between the horizontal, the slope, and the downward gravitational component is a right angle composed of the angles $\theta,90,$ and $90-\theta$, with the  $90-\theta$ angle occurring in the top right corner. Because that angle forms a 90 degree angle with the angle in question, then the unknown angle ($\phi$) must be $90-90+\theta = \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle made by the incline, ground and mg AND the triangle made by mg , mg cos $\theta$, and the dash line connecting these two vectors are similar.